# Automatically display legends in Google visualization charts

Tags: google-visualization, legend

I have a sample Google visualization dashboard in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23JeU/1/) in which the chart is drawn as,

```
 Chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
          'containerId': 'chart1',
          'options': {
            'width': 600,
            'height': 180,
         'isStacked': true,
         'legend': 'top',
          }
        });
```

For **CPU** in control picker, there is only `value1`. But the chart legend shows both. How can I hide the legend `value2` if it has 0 and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the state changes on the control, you need to get the data used by the chart and parse it to determine whether or not there are non-0 values in the selected range for each data series.  If there are non-0 values, add the data series to the chart's `view.columns` parameter, otherwise leave it out:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(categoryPicker, 'statechange', function () {
    google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(Chart, 'ready', function () {
        var cols = [0];
        var dt = Chart.getDataTable();
        for (var i = 1; i < dt.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
            var range = dt.getColumnRange(i);
            console.dir(range);
            // assumes there are no null values
            if (range.min !== 0 || range.max !== 0) {
                cols.push(i);
            }
        }
        var view = Chart.getView() || {};
        view.columns = cols;
        Chart.setView(view);
        Chart.draw();
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/23JeU/2/)

Comment: Thanks... Also how can i stick the color for bars. I used `'colors': ['blue','red']` in option but when i select `CPU`, the value1 is blue and if i select `Memory` value2 is blue.

Comment: You have to track which series are displayed, and set the colors appropriately on each draw.  Call `Chart.setOption('colors', [/* array of colors */]);`.